# Deadlock tracing on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-deadlocks

I am working on investigation of deadlocks traces, but I have found deadlocks with no victimized process, so what does a deadlock mean if no victimized process was traced or when inputbuf of victimized process is empty?

please find below an XML Graph of deadlock with no inputbuf defined for victimized process.

```
<event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" id="123" version="1" timestamp="2014-05-04T12:44:37.917Z">
  <data name="xml_report">
    <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
    <value><deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process1369fdc8"/>
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process1369fdc8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:1859678" waittime="39886" ownerId="26953881" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2014-05-04T15:44:01.870" XDES="0x7b2bca2f0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="79" kpid="9072" status="suspended" spid="94" sbid="0" ecid="15" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2014-05-04T15:44:01.540" lastbatchcompleted="2014-05-04T15:44:01.540" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="E-DHQ-UMRSDB" hostpid="21448" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="26953881" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="" line="17" stmtstart="1166" stmtend="1840" sqlhandle="0x03000700cc7bde09501015010da300000100000000000000">
    </frame>
    <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="68" sqlhandle="0x01000700cb9c391ff09dd28a0a0000000000000000000000">
    </frame>
    <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process12d76bc8" taskpriority="0" logused="473152" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:1859677" waittime="1787" ownerId="26919083" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2014-05-04T15:42:05.963" XDES="0xadb2a63b0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="55" kpid="23948" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2014-05-04T15:44:40" lastbatchcompleted="2014-05-04T15:44:39.950" lastattention="2014-05-04T15:31:58.570" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="E-DHQ-UMRSAPPN2" hostpid="21300" loginname="SEC\S-ISD-UMRS" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="26919083" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="1270" sqlhandle="0x02000000e5c9362166f41bf7f95f3653aba53c8419996b90">
    </frame>
    <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@p0 int,@p1 varchar(8000),@p2 varchar(8000),@p3 int,@p4 varchar(8000),@p5 int,@p6 int,@p7 int,@p8 float,@p9 varchar(8000),@p10 tinyint,@p11 int,@p12 int,@p13 varchar(8000),@p14 int,@p15 varchar(8000),@p16 varchar(8000),@p17 varchar(8000),@p18 varchar(8000),@p19 varchar(8000),@p20 int,@p21 int,@p22 int,@p23 int,@p24 datetime,@p25 datetime,@p26 int,@p27 varchar(8000),@p28 int,@p29 int,@p30 int,@p31 datetime,@p32 int,@p33 float,@p34 int,@p35 int,@p36 int,@p37 int,@p38 int,@p39 int,@p40 varchar(8000),@p41 int,@p42 varchar(8000),@p43 decimal(18,8),@p44 smalldatetime,@p45 smalldatetime,@p46 varchar(8000),@p47 int,@p48 smalldatetime)UPDATE [dbo].[Meter]
SET [ReadingStatusID] = @p47, [LastEditDate] = @p48
WHERE ([ID] = @p0) AND ([SerialNumber] = @p1) AND ([SubscribtionNumber] = @p2) AND ([SubscriberID] = @p3) AND ([SubscriberNumber] = @p4) AND ([NumberOfDigits] IS NULL) AND ([BreakerCapacity] = @p5) AND ([TariffTypeID] = @p6) AND ([BusinessUnitID] = @p7) AND ([MultiplicationFactor] = @p8) AND ([AccumulationNumber   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1859678" dbid="7" objectname="" id="lockb618fbd00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594953859072">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process12d76bc8" mode="IX"/>
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1369fdc8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1859677" dbid="7" objectname="" id="lock1e573c580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594953859072">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1369fdc8" mode="U"/>
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process12d76bc8" mode="IX" requestType="wait"/>
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
</value>
    <text />
  </data>
</event>
```

Comment: Could you post a deadlock graph XML?

Comment: Without knowing more, it sounds like an intra-query deadlock.  I would advise trying to set Max DOP = 1 and give that a whirl.

Comment: @RazzleDazzle And if it were two processes deadlocked on each other, would you recommend serializable isolation level or maybe setting the database into single user mode? It's not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on these SQL server flags.  I have found that these flags are very useful to locate the offending SQL and also give you extra information.

```
dbcc tracestatus(-1)
DBCC Traceon (1204, 1222, -1)
dbcc tracestatus(-1)

-- 1204 Deadlock resources and type of locks participating in a deadlock
-- 1222 Deadlock resources and also current command affected.

/*
dbcc traceoff (1204 ,-1)
dbcc traceoff (1222 ,-1)
*/
```

RosSQL.blogspot.com

Comment: How would these TFs reduce the deadlocks??

Comment: The flags themselves do not reduce the deadlocks, but they allow you to see more data and data in cases where profiler would not show any.  This I have found allows me to see the offending Stored Procedures (or whatever is locking) and make the code changes needed.

Comment: Sure, 1222 helps a lot in getting to the cause. But pls remove the "reduce" part from the answer, it simply isn't so.

Comment: Thank you dean!  After seeing what I wrote, I realize I did not type what I meant to say!  Thanks again.